# How can Stack Overflow be used as a collaborative tool?

Tags: discussion, collaboration

Stack Overflow is a Q&A tool imposing a certain structure in the way the dialog is handled between OP and the rest of the community.

But let's say a bunch of site users are following a [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) or [iTunes U](http://www.apple.com/education/itunes-u/) class and they want to talk about course homework or other matters. What's the best way to open discussion about class topics?

Comment: SO is not well-suited for this in its present form (and it is probably beyond the stated mission of SO).

Comment: There is a tool for this called chat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't used iTunesU, but every Coursera class has its own Q&A discussion forum.  I think it's better to use that resource along with other people who are in your class rather than try to start a discussion on a Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer the Stack Exchange Q&A format, use one of the [Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones).

For instance, it only takes a few minutes to create a site on [Shapado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapado) (they claim [it only takes 8 seconds](https://shapado.com/questions)). Tip: use [the free plan at the bottom](https://shapado.com/plans):

[image]